# how to display the categories added in pickerview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm new to iphone development. I added 3 types of categories to a UIImagePickerController (For example, "Wild animals", "African animals" and "Water animals")

If the user taps on "wild animals", for example, how can I display just that category of images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the delegate for pickerView.

The following delegate method will be called for each item selection

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView  *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row  inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

The row value gives the selected item

Place a imageView in the view and change the image according to selected value.

```
self.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"wildanimals.jpg"];
```

Comment: (void)viewDidLoad {
 
 
 images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 
 [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bufflo_large.jpg"]];
 [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"goat.jpg"]];
 [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pig.jpg"]];
 [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cow.jpg"]];
 [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_large.jpg"]];
 [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sheep.jpg"]];

Comment: self.imageView.image=[images objectAtIndex:row];

Comment: have you assign IB for your imageView?